# Proof, if true, that a topological n-sphere can be approximated by a polytope homemorphic to it?

Tags: general-topology, triangulation

Given a set in (n+1) Euclidean space homeomorphic to the n-sphere, how do you show the existence of a simplicial complex also homeomorphic to the n-sphere arbitrarily close to it, if this is possible?  I can find a proof for a diffeomorphism, but I was hoping to go the extra step.

(EDIT: What I mean by "the existence of a simplicial complex... arbitrarily close" is that, for every positive $\epsilon$, the existence of a complex every point of which is within $\epsilon$ of some point in the original set.)

Here's my initial thought: start with a homeomorphism from the boundary of the (n+1)-simplex (since this is homeomorphic to the sphere).  Break the boundary down by barycentric subdivision, and use the convex hulls of the images of the vertices.  By uniform continuity (since the simplex's boundary is compact), you can get arbitrarily close by this method, but the problem is that it isn't, in general, injective.  It would be enough to show that it was injective for infinite steps, so that you could just skip over those that aren't.  My hope was that you could maybe show that it only fails at finite steps (I don't at all know this is true), and I was thinking I might be able to get a contradiction by taking a representative pair of simplices in the domain at each step whose images under this new function meet and, assuming there are infinite steps, using compactness to pass the pairs of midpoints to a convergent subsequence, whose limit must be identical, since otherwise, eventually, simplices too small to meet would meet.  The problem is I can't think of a problem with them converging to an identical pair.  Is this tactic a fool's errand?  Is there a similar tactic that might get me there, maybe altering the function when it fails to be injective?

I'd prefer a constructive proof if possible.

Comment: You should try to give a precise interpretation of "arbitrarily close to it".  Anyway, I doubt that it is always possible. Have a look at Alexander's horned sphere in  $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: What I meant was that for any $\epsilon$, there's a polytope every point of which is within $\epsilon$ of some point of the original.  You're right I was imprecise; I'll add that.

By that definition, I don't see how Alexander's horned sphere is a problem.  You can get a sphere within an arbitrary distance by taking the construction process out a finite number of steps and closing them, and the resulting collection of tori is simple to approximate.

Comment: In that case you are right. I had the suspicion that for any embedding $f : S^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ you want to find a polyhedral embedding $g :  S^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $d(f(x), g(x)) < \epsilon$ for all $x$.

Comment: I'm curious.  Why is it you think that the horned sphere would be a counterexample to your stronger statement?  Only that my initial strategy, if it could be shown to work (i.e., to be injective for an infinite set of steps), would fulfill the stronger statement, so your counterexample would debunk that strategy at least.

Comment: After I considered again about the problem, I retract my doubt concerning the horned sphere. It is obtained by iterating polyhedral embeddings, and the subsequent steps produce smaller and smaller perturbations.